# Insert iframe inside of canvas with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas, iframe

### Problem

Hi, I am trying to figure out how I can use javascript to embed an iframe inside of a canvas. I would like all the content in the iframe to be interactable meaning that if I have a hover effect in my website I should be able to hover the same content inside of my iframe embedded in my canvas. I would also like to do this using pure javascript. Here is the code for my canvas:

```
<canvas id="mycanvas" width=512 height=512 ></canvas>
```

Comment: Pretty sure you can't embed an iframe in a canvas (because a canvas does not render HTML).  What you maybe want to look at is positioning a transparent iframe in front of an identically sized canvas

Comment: I am creating a webvr scene using A-frame (https://aframe.io) and I need to embed html on a 3d plane in my scene. I have only been able to embed a canvas in my scene so the iframe must be inside the canvas. Otherwise I the idea you posted looks good. I'm also pretty sure there's a way that you can use javascript to embed the iframe in the canvas if html is impossible.

Comment: For your project, have a look at https://lume.io/ But no you can't append an iframe in a canvas, a simple search on what is the canvas should have told you so.